# PowerShell - Concatenating two strings with underscore inbetween not working?

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to append a timestamp to the name of a file and then move that file into another directory.
Here is a code example:

```
$sourceFiles= Get-ChildItem $sourcePath\* -Include *.csv

ForEach($sourceFile in $sourceFiles)
{
    $fileNameWithoutExtension = $sourceFile.BaseName
    $timestamp = $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm_ss)
    $processedFile = Join-Path -Path $processedPath -ChildPath "$fileNameWithoutExtension_$timestamp.csv"   
    Move-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $processedFile
}
```

When I execute this it seems like `"$fileNameWithoutExtension_$timestamp.csv"` completely ignores the content of the `$fileNameWithoutExtension` variable and only includes the timestamp into the file name. I also debugged this already and checked the content of the `$fileNameWithoutExtension` variable and it does indeed contain the correct filename without the extension. Why is that and how can I create the file name correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the underscore is a valid character in a variable name (look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-5.1#using-variables-in-commands-and-expressions)), so PowerShell basically concatenates `$fileNameWithoutExtension_`  + `$timestamp` + `.csv`. The first variable (name incl. underscore) doesn't exist, so it's interpreted as null / empty.

Try one of these solutions (of course, there are more):

```
# curly-bracket-notation for variables
"${fileNameWithoutExtension}_${timestamp}.csv"

# sub-expression operator
"$($fileNameWithoutExtension)_$($timestamp).csv"

# escape character
"$fileNameWithoutExtension`_$timestamp.csv"

# format operator
"{0}_{1}.csv" -f $fileNameWithoutExtension, $timestamp

# string concatenation
($fileNameWithoutExtension + "_" + $timestamp + ".csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! I tried your first solution but there seems to be an error in it because it includes the brackets in the file name. However, the second one works just fine!